# How to read in ALL YAML variables as strings using Python

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file where the data contains both strings and integers.  When loading YAML file and producing dictionary, YAML "intelligently" makes unquoted integers as type int.  Is there any easy way to have YAML treat everything as a string without putting in double quotes around all integers?

Here is a portion of the YAML file:

```
devices:
  rtr1:
    reachable: True
    instances: [Region-58,] 
    system_id: 0101.8800.0008
    level: Level-2
    isis_lsps:
      - lsp_id: RTR1CA22CWP.00-00
        instance: Region-58 
        prot_supported: "IPv4, IPv6"
        hostname: RTR1CA22CWP
        te_router_id: 10.1.0.8
        extended_reach:
          - ext_reach_id: 0101.8890.0207.00
            metric: 10
            adm_group: 0x601
            local_int_ip: 10.14.2.21
            remote_int_ip: 10.14.2.20
            max_bw: 400000
            max_reserve_bw: 380000
            te_metric: 10
```

After using yaml_load, the numbers are of type "int".
For example, metric: 10

Is there anyway to have yaml_load treat the number 10 as a string without having to put double quotes around it.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the `Loader` argument into `yaml.load()` like so:

`yaml.load(yaml, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)`

This disables automatic value conversion, as `BaseLoader` "does not resolve or support any tags and construct only basic Python objects: lists, dictionaries, and Unicode strings." - See reference below

[PyYAML Documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)