# Why the yaml can't load value as expected?

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2

I use next minimal example to explain my problem:

**test.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import jinja2
import yaml
from yaml import CSafeLoader as SafeLoader

devices = [
    "usb_otg_path: 1:8",
    "usb_otg_path: m1:8",
    "usb_otg_path: 18",
]

for device in devices:
    template = jinja2.Template(device)
    device_template = template.render()
    print(device_template)
    obj = yaml.load(device_template, Loader=SafeLoader)
    print(obj)
```

**The run result is:**

```
root@pie:~# python3 test.py
usb_otg_path: 1:8
{'usb_otg_path': 68}
usb_otg_path: m1:8
{'usb_otg_path': 'm1:8'}
usb_otg_path: 18
{'usb_otg_path': 18}
```

You could see if the value of `device_template` is `usb_otg_path: 1:8`, then after `yaml.load`, the `1:8` becomes `68`, looks like because we have `:` in it. But it's ok for other 2 inputs.

You know above is a simplify of a complex system, in which `"usb_otg_path: 1:8"` is the input value which I could not change, also the `yaml.load` is the basic mechanism it used to change a string to a python object.

Then if possible for me to get `{'usb_otg_path': '1:8'}` with some small changes (We need to upstream to that project, so may can't do big changes to affect others)? Something like change any parameters of `yaml.load` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML allows numerical literals (scalars) formatted as `x:y:z` and interprets them as "sexagesimal," that is to say: base 60.

`1:8` is thus interpreted by YAML as `1*60**1 + 8*60**0`, obviously giving you `68`.

Notably you also have `m1:8` as a string and `18` as a number. You sound like you want all strings? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58455936/3058609) might be useful:

> `yaml.load(yaml, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)`
>
> This disables automatic value conversion, as BaseLoader "does not resolve or support any tags and construct only basic Python objects: lists, dictionaries, and Unicode strings." - See reference below

Comment: Wow, it works, thanks ~~ Either int or string ok for me.

Comment: Sexagesimals were in the YAML 1.1 specification. That has been superseded over ten years ago by YAML 1.2, that no longer supports them. The OP's real problem is using an outdated YAML parser.

Comment: @Anthon How can I confirm the yaml specification? I use `Python 3.7.3 (default, Dec 20 2019, 18:57:59)`, and `python3 -c "import yaml; print(yaml.__version__)"` prints `3.13`, you mean python3's yaml library always use the old 1.1 specification 10 years ago?

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for the information, you are correct, from https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/, I saw `PyYAML features a complete YAML 1.1 parser`. Unfortunately, this is an opensource project which still use pyyaml which can't be controlled by me. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @atline If you can change it then you'll have to work around it. IIRC PyYAML refuses to load documents tagged `%YAML 1.2`, but I am not sure (it should throw a warning and try and load). When you dump and explicitly ask for a TAG, it will output `%YAML 1.1`